# Civimail reply tracking and forwarding does not seem to work

Tags: civimail

I have CiviCRM 5.48.2 on Drupal 8 and I configured CiviMail account for bounces:

[image: civimail account]

In my mailing I have set "Track replies" and "Forward replies".
In the Civimail settings I have checked "Track CiviMail replies".

When the recipient replies and "fetch_bounces" job is executed no activity is created and no email is sent to the sender.

In the mail account the email is correctly placed in the "processed" folder.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you certain that replies are managed via 'bounce' inbox and job? i wouldn't have thought so. i'd assume it would need a separate inbox and then perhaps the specific Sch Job "Process Inbound Emails (Hourly) - Inserts activity for a contact or a case by retrieving inbound emails from a mail directory
API Entity: job
API Action: fetch_activities"

Comment: If in my email client I do "Reply" it shows me the "bouncecivicrm+..." that is the localpart of my bounce email account. And this email is picked up by bounce job. The fetch_activities works in another account.

Comment: ok, that seems to confirm process. sorry for doubting you

Comment: @petednz-fuzion can you try yourself please? Maybe I did something wrong and would really like to solve this problem.